# How to declare a global, globalThis in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I've been googling to find some updated answer on how to declare globals in Typescript. But I'm not sure which tutorial/guide has the most updated solution.

Anyhow I'm trying to get my custom global declares `d.ts` to work.
Right now I've setup so that my Typescript project is built and bundled using webpack/ts-loader.

My tsconfig.json file looks as following. Guides I've read said things that I don't really need to set `typeRoots` as Typescript can find the types by it self. I've tried with and without anyhow, and both resulted in the same.

```
{
    "files": [
        "app.ts",
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "target": "es5",
        "declaration": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "./typings/",
            "../../../../../node_modules/@types/"
        ]
    }
}
```

And my `d.ts` file which I named to `soho.d.ts` contains the following

```
declare global {
    namespace Soho {

    }
    interface Window {
        Soho: Soho;
    }

    interface Soho {
        Locale: any;
    }
}
```

I get the following error though in webpack

```
TS2304: Cannot find name 'Soho'
```

In the code I'm trying to use my global as following

```
Soho.Locale
```

Did I set my `tsconfig.json` file correct, or is it something wrong with my `d.ts` file?

Comment: Perhaps you can simplify it to `declare const Soho: Soho`. And no need to wrap everything into `declare global {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an error in my `tsconfig.json` file. And the error is in the specified `files` property which tells Typescript to only use that file during compilation.

Therefore my custom `d.ts` files where omitted thus the errors.

So as for the solution. Either remove `files` property or include the folder with custom `d.ts` by using the `include` property.